# Cloud shared memory management in openstack

Tags: cloud, data-analysis, openstack

I am going to do a data analysis, which size is 2TB, by using python. There is not enough memory for my local machine. Is it possible to setup a cloud by using openstack and let the cluster share their memory? Any example?

Comment: Your question is too broad and doesn't show what you've tried. Perhaps it can be done on your machine. This is why you get voted down. Don't get discouraged; SO is a great community, if you're willing to put in the right amount of effort.

Comment: I have tried on my own machine which has 4GB memory. It's out of memory when I was processing the 2TB data. On the other hand, I have considered using hadoop, but the map-reduce requires me to re-code everything, even if a simple count function. That is the reason why a shared memory system can help, which may extend the memory as large as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with OpenStack.

What you are describing is a [distributed shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory) system. I believe that [ScaleMP](http://www.scalemp.com) sells a product called vSMP that does this. Note that historically, it's been very difficult to get good performance out of a distributed shared memory system because of a problem called [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) (I have no idea how much this affects ScaleMP, I've never used it).

You can also buy a more expensive system with specialized hardware for supporting distributed shared memory, like an [SGI UV](http://www.sgi.com/products/servers/uv/).

You're probably best off modifying your code to take advantage of something like Hadoop or MPI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could implement inside of your cloud instances.

You could basically create many instances each with a large ramfs.  Then place all the ramfs on the many nodes into a network distributed filesystem such as openAFS, gluster, or luster.

That would be an approach.